# Why isn't the data-id being selected by my function?

Tags: javascript, mootools

I am trying to get the data id to be shown in an alert menu when the user clicks on a link. But instead of the number I am getting 0 for each link.

[Here is a JSFiddle of the issue](http://jsfiddle.net/SGU8E/)

JS

```
$$('.postItem').addEvent('click', function(){
  var id = $('data-id');
    alert(+id);
});
```

HTML

```
<a class="postItem" data-id="9" href="#">Number Nine</a>
```

I have also tried using $$ to select the data-id but this didn't work either.

Comment: Dunno about Mootools, but in POJS you'd write: `var id = this.getAttribute('data-id')`.

Comment: And in jQuery it would be `$(this).data('id')` or `$(this).attr('data-id')`.

Comment: @RobG I just your pure JS code and it worked, if you wish to add it as a answer I can accept. Thank you :)

Comment: if you work with mootools and have a lot of `data-nnn` attributes, I recommend you use my data-mootools plugin, which works like the jQuery `.data()` api and will even serialise JSON to objects. https://github.com/DimitarChristoff/data-mootools

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mootools `$` is converting element to mootools `Element` by it's id. so in your case you used it wrong, `data-id` in your case is an attribute so you can use the `getAttribute` function:

http://jsfiddle.net/SGU8E/6/

```
$$('.postItem').addEvent('click', function(e){
    var el = e.target;
    var id = el.getAttribute('data-id');
    alert(id);
});
```